# How to create a view and a concat without an error

Tags: mysql, sql, view, concatenation

I'm not sure what the problem is, I've tried various things, including rearranging the tables various times, messing with the quotes after CONCAT, and adding `ORDER BY employee_id` at the very end.

```sql
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER (
  supplier_id INT,
  company_name VARCHAR(50),
  country VARCHAR(30),
  sales_contact_name VARCHAR(60),
  email VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id))
  ;

CREATE TABLE COFFEE (
  coffee_id INT,
  shop_id INT,
  supplier_id INT, 
  coffee_name VARCHAR(30),
  price_per_pound NUMERIC(5,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (coffee_id))
  ;


CREATE TABLE COFFEE_SHOP (
  shop_id INT,
  shop_name VARCHAR(50),
  city VARCHAR(50),
  state CHAR(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (shop_id))
;

  

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  employee_id INT,
  first_name VARCHAR(30),
  last_name VARCHAR(30),
  hire_date DATE,
  job_title VARCHAR(30),
  shop_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (employee_id))
  ;

  

  
   ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT fk_shop_id  FOREIGN KEY (shop_id) REFERENCES COFFEE_SHOP(shop_id);

 ALTER TABLE COFFEE ADD FOREIGN KEY (shop_id) REFERENCES COFFEE_SHOP(shop_id);

  ALTER TABLE COFFEE ADD CONSTRAINT fk_supplier_id  FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) REFERENCES SUPPLIER(supplier_id);

  
CREATE VIEW mocha AS 
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS employee_full_name
employee_id
hire_date
job_title
shop_id
FROM EMPLOYEE
;
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'employee_id
hire_date
job_title
shop_id
FROM EMPLOYEE' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors where you are missing commas i.e.

```sql
CREATE VIEW mocha AS 
SELECT 
    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS employee_full_name,
    employee_id,
    hire_date,
    job_title,
    shop_id
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Let me know if this works for you.